# Faces in XRay mode not selecting properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am new to blender. When I toggle XRay mode on and try to select a face of an object, it does not select when I click on it. I keep clicking and by some chance it selects sometimes or else it might select nothing or the face behind it. Although, this does not happen when I turn off the XRay mode.

[image]
What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

There is a little black dot on each face:

[image]

You can select by clicking near it.

If you feel these dots are too small, you can change their size in the preferences (in Edit menu), in "Themes" at the end of the "3D viewport" section:

[image]

Comment: @AayushAggarwal Additionally I just want to say, when lemon writes "You can select by clicking near it" this means, when your cursor is somewhere near between two dots, the face with the closest dot is selected.